# Browserify document is undefined

Tags: node.js, browserify

i just found browserify, which sounds really cool. However i try to append a canvas element to the body(filename : **Renderer.js**):

```
  window.document.body.appendChild(this.canvas)
  module.exports = Renderer
```

And i also have a **main.js**

```
var Renderer = require("Renderer.js")
var r = new Renderer();
```

So i build the bundle like this:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

And when i start the project:

```
node server.js
```

I get the following error message

- ReferenceError : document is not defined (if only document.body)
- And window is not defined (when window.document.body)

Can someone explain this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: Does it help if you declare those variables at the beginning of the script? Like just adding `var window;` or `var document;`?

Comment: I dont really understand?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run that browserify code on the server? Please do not, as in the server there is not `window` element, whereas node only has `global`. Instead, you need to use your browser to download the browserified code and execute on your browser.

Note that, browserify library is mainly to bundle packages for client to use `require` styled call.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, this Code runs on the Client